# Duplicate bible verses - Does it also duplicate in the original text?

Tags: hebrew, textual-criticism

I read the Proverbs and I suddenly notice that there is duplicated text

PROVERBS 22:3

> The prudent sees danger and hides himself,
>
> but the simple go on and suffer for it.

PROVERBS 27:12

> The prudent sees danger and hides himself,
>
> but the simple go on and suffer for it.

So I looked it up and found out that there are several duplicate verses in the Bible

source [here](https://honza.ca/2013/06/duplicate-bible-verses)

```
Duplicate Bible verses

The text of the ESV was used.

Number of verses that appear more than once: 235 (i.e. the number of list items below).

    Genesis 36:41, 1 Chronicles 1:52
    Matthew 8:20, Luke 9:58
    2 Kings 19:5, Isaiah 37:5
    2 Kings 19:2, Isaiah 37:2
    1 Chronicles 16:10, Psalms 105:3
    Ezra 2:53, Nehemiah 7:55
    2 Samuel 22:46, Psalms 18:45
    2 Kings 18:3, 2 Chronicles 29:2
    1 Kings 12:11, 2 Chronicles 10:11
    2 Kings 19:34, Isaiah 37:35
    Ezekiel 40:29, Ezekiel 40:33
    Genesis 10:27, 1 Chronicles 1:21
    Jeremiah 10:15, Jeremiah 51:18
    1 Kings 8:14, 2 Chronicles 6:3
    1 Kings 12:6, 2 Chronicles 10:6
    2 Samuel 23:19, 1 Chronicles 11:21
    Genesis 10:16, 1 Chronicles 1:14
    2 Kings 16:4, 2 Chronicles 28:4
    1 Kings 12:1, 2 Chronicles 10:1
    Psalms 60:8, Psalms 108:9
    Genesis 10:2, 1 Chronicles 1:5
    1 Chronicles 16:22, Psalms 105:15
    2 Kings 22:18, 2 Chronicles 34:26
    2 Samuel 23:37, 1 Chronicles 11:39
    Job 4:1, Job 15:1, Job 22:1
    1 Kings 22:7, 2 Chronicles 18:6
    Numbers 29:18, Numbers 29:21, Numbers 29:24, Numbers 29:27, Numbers 29:30, Numbers 29:33
    Matthew 26:41, Mark 14:38
    Proverbs 18:8, Proverbs 26:22
    1 Kings 12:4, 2 Chronicles 10:4
    Matthew 26:32, Mark 14:28
    Ezra 2:3, Nehemiah 7:8
    Genesis 36:37, 1 Chronicles 1:48
    2 Kings 18:20, Isaiah 36:5
    Genesis 36:34, 1 Chronicles 1:45
    Numbers 7:15, Numbers 7:21, Numbers 7:27, Numbers 7:33, Numbers 7:39, Numbers 7:45, Numbers 7:51, Numbers 7:57, Numbers 7:63, Numbers 7:69, Numbers 7:75, Numbers 7:81
    1 Kings 8:35, 2 Chronicles 6:26
    Ezra 2:51, Nehemiah 7:53
    Psalms 59:6, Psalms 59:14
    1 Kings 12:17, 2 Chronicles 10:17
    2 Kings 21:5, 2 Chronicles 33:5
    Leviticus 24:13, Numbers 16:36
    Genesis 10:26, 1 Chronicles 1:20
    1 Kings 22:18, 2 Chronicles 18:17
    2 Kings 14:12, 2 Chronicles 25:22
    2 Samuel 8:5, 1 Chronicles 18:5
    Luke 20:43, Acts 2:35
    Mark 12:40, Luke 20:47
    Ezra 2:16, Nehemiah 7:21
    2 Kings 20:17, Isaiah 39:6
    Job 40:3, Job 42:1
    2 Kings 8:18, 2 Chronicles 21:6
    Proverbs 14:12, Proverbs 16:25
    1 Chronicles 16:24, Psalms 96:3
    Exodus 40:1, Leviticus 5:14, Leviticus 6:1, Leviticus 6:8, Leviticus 6:19, Leviticus 6:24, Leviticus 7:22, Leviticus 7:28, Leviticus 8:1, Leviticus 12:1, Leviticus 14:1, Leviticus 20:1, Leviticus 23:1, Leviticus 24:1, Leviticus 27:1, Numbers 4:21, Numbers 5:1, Numbers 6:22, Numbers 9:9, Numbers 10:1, Numbers 13:1, Numbers 15:1, Numbers 15:17, Numbers 17:1, Numbers 26:52, Numbers 28:1, Numbers 31:1, Numbers 34:1, Numbers 34:16
    1 Kings 8:17, 2 Chronicles 6:7
    Numbers 29:16, Numbers 29:25
    2 Samuel 22:9, Psalms 18:8
    Judges 17:6, Judges 21:25
    Matthew 24:19, Mark 13:17
    Job 27:1, Job 29:1
    Ezekiel 40:34, Ezekiel 40:37
    Psalms 42:11, Psalms 43:5
    Jeremiah 6:14, Jeremiah 8:11
    Genesis 36:42, 1 Chronicles 1:53
    1 Kings 22:13, 2 Chronicles 18:12
    1 Kings 12:12, 2 Chronicles 10:12
    Ezra 2:43, Nehemiah 7:46
    1 Kings 22:29, 2 Chronicles 18:28
    2 Kings 19:26, Isaiah 37:27
    Ezra 2:27, Nehemiah 7:31
    2 Kings 23:32, 2 Kings 23:37
    1 Kings 22:9, 2 Chronicles 18:8
    2 Kings 18:13, Isaiah 36:1
    Matthew 6:27, Luke 12:25
    Psalms 107:6, Psalms 107:13, Psalms 107:19, Psalms 107:28
    1 Kings 8:31, 2 Chronicles 6:22
    Leviticus 2:3, Leviticus 2:10
    2 Samuel 22:31, Psalms 18:30
    1 Kings 10:6, 2 Chronicles 9:5
    Matthew 24:46, Luke 12:43
    Matthew 7:8, Luke 11:10
    Matthew 24:18, Mark 13:16
    Ezra 2:58, Nehemiah 7:60
    Leviticus 3:10, Leviticus 3:15
    Exodus 16:11, Exodus 31:12, Numbers 25:10, Numbers 27:6
    2 Samuel 7:17, 1 Chronicles 17:15
    Matthew 12:41, Luke 11:32
    1 Kings 22:25, 2 Chronicles 18:24
    Proverbs 22:3, Proverbs 27:12
    2 Samuel 23:38, 1 Chronicles 11:40
    Genesis 10:13, 1 Chronicles 1:11
    Jeremiah 29:30, Jeremiah 35:12
    2 Kings 18:23, Isaiah 36:8
    Matthew 12:27, Luke 11:19
    2 Kings 19:30, Isaiah 37:31
    Exodus 13:1, Exodus 25:1, Exodus 30:11, Exodus 30:17, Exodus 30:22, Exodus 31:1, Numbers 15:37, Numbers 31:25
    Numbers 7:25, Numbers 7:31, Numbers 7:37, Numbers 7:43, Numbers 7:49, Numbers 7:55, Numbers 7:61, Numbers 7:67, Numbers 7:73, Numbers 7:79
    Ezra 2:7, Nehemiah 7:12
    1 Corinthians 1:3, 2 Corinthians 1:2, Ephesians 1:2, Philippians 1:2, 2 Thessalonians 1:2, Philemon 1:3
    Jeremiah 10:16, Jeremiah 51:19
    Numbers 7:16, Numbers 7:22, Numbers 7:28, Numbers 7:34, Numbers 7:40, Numbers 7:46, Numbers 7:52, Numbers 7:58, Numbers 7:64, Numbers 7:70, Numbers 7:76, Numbers 7:82
    1 Kings 10:14, 2 Chronicles 9:13
    2 Kings 19:11, Isaiah 37:11
    2 Samuel 22:10, Psalms 18:9
    1 Chronicles 16:14, Psalms 105:7
    2 Samuel 8:7, 1 Chronicles 18:7
    Psalms 67:3, Psalms 67:5
    2 Samuel 23:14, 1 Chronicles 11:16
    Matthew 11:6, Luke 7:23
    1 Kings 8:18, 2 Chronicles 6:8
    Genesis 10:29, 1 Chronicles 1:23
    Isaiah 35:10, Isaiah 51:11
    2 Kings 19:10, Isaiah 37:10
    1 Kings 7:25, 2 Chronicles 4:4
    Matthew 24:35, Mark 13:31, Luke 21:33
    Ezra 2:37, Nehemiah 7:40
    Matthew 12:30, Luke 11:23
    2 Kings 22:15, 2 Chronicles 34:23
    1 Chronicles 16:21, Psalms 105:14
    2 Kings 25:2, Jeremiah 52:5
    Psalms 57:5, Psalms 57:11, Psalms 108:5
    1 Chronicles 16:20, Psalms 105:13
    1 Kings 12:19, 2 Chronicles 10:19
    Revelation 2:29, Revelation 3:6, Revelation 3:13
    Genesis 10:3, 1 Chronicles 1:6
    2 Samuel 22:19, Psalms 18:18
    Mark 10:18, Luke 18:19
    Psalms 107:8, Psalms 107:15, Psalms 107:21, Psalms 107:31
    Matthew 24:32, Mark 13:28
    Ezra 2:9, Nehemiah 7:14
    Exodus 14:1, Numbers 7:4
    2 Samuel 22:30, Psalms 18:29
    1 Kings 8:12, 2 Chronicles 6:1
    Genesis 10:6, 1 Chronicles 1:8
    2 Samuel 10:9, 1 Chronicles 19:10
    1 Kings 8:15, 2 Chronicles 6:4
    Matthew 11:9, Luke 7:26
    Matthew 24:34, Mark 13:30
    1 Kings 10:23, 2 Chronicles 9:22
    Genesis 46:11, 1 Chronicles 6:1
    Mark 10:15, Luke 18:17
    2 Samuel 22:34, Psalms 18:33
    Song of Solomon 2:7, Song of Solomon 3:5
    1 Samuel 31:1, 1 Chronicles 10:1
    1 Kings 22:17, 2 Chronicles 18:16
    2 Kings 19:13, Isaiah 37:13
    1 Kings 12:9, 2 Chronicles 10:9
    1 Kings 8:24, 2 Chronicles 6:15
    2 Samuel 22:6, Psalms 18:5
    Jeremiah 16:1, Ezekiel 6:1, Ezekiel 7:1, Ezekiel 12:1, Ezekiel 13:1, Ezekiel 17:1, Ezekiel 18:1, Ezekiel 21:1, Ezekiel 23:1, Ezekiel 24:15, Ezekiel 25:1, Ezekiel 27:1, Ezekiel 28:1, Ezekiel 28:20, Ezekiel 30:1, Ezekiel 33:1, Ezekiel 33:23, Ezekiel 34:1, Ezekiel 35:1, Ezekiel 36:16, Ezekiel 37:15, Ezekiel 38:1
    Genesis 10:15, 1 Chronicles 1:13
    1 Kings 15:16, 1 Kings 15:32
    Jeremiah 7:1, Jeremiah 11:1, Jeremiah 18:1, Jeremiah 30:1
    Leviticus 13:1, Leviticus 14:33, Leviticus 15:1, Numbers 2:1, Numbers 4:1, Numbers 4:17
    1 Chronicles 16:8, Psalms 105:1
    1 Samuel 31:2, 1 Chronicles 10:2
    1 Kings 7:23, 2 Chronicles 4:2
    2 Samuel 22:4, Psalms 18:3
    Ezra 2:38, Nehemiah 7:41
    Jeremiah 32:26, Jeremiah 33:19, Jeremiah 33:23
    Ezra 2:23, Nehemiah 7:27
    Matthew 11:10, Luke 7:27
    2 Kings 19:7, Isaiah 37:7
    Matthew 26:46, Mark 14:42
    2 Samuel 7:4, 1 Chronicles 17:3
    Job 11:1, Job 20:1
    2 Kings 24:19, Jeremiah 52:2
    2 Kings 19:33, Isaiah 37:34
    Ezra 2:39, Nehemiah 7:42
    Matthew 7:3, Luke 6:41
    2 Samuel 22:40, Psalms 18:39
    Ezekiel 11:14, Ezekiel 12:17, Ezekiel 12:21, Ezekiel 12:26, Ezekiel 14:2, Ezekiel 14:12, Ezekiel 15:1, Ezekiel 20:2, Ezekiel 20:45, Ezekiel 21:8, Ezekiel 22:17, Ezekiel 22:23, Zechariah 6:9
    1 Kings 8:36, 2 Chronicles 6:27
    1 Kings 19:10, 1 Kings 19:14
    Numbers 29:28, Numbers 29:38
    Proverbs 6:11, Proverbs 24:34
    2 Kings 19:1, Isaiah 37:1
    1 Kings 22:34, 2 Chronicles 18:33
    Jeremiah 10:14, Jeremiah 51:17
    Psalms 60:9, Psalms 108:10
    Genesis 36:35, 1 Chronicles 1:46
    1 Kings 22:28, 2 Chronicles 18:27
    Exodus 20:6, Deuteronomy 5:10
    Ezra 2:34, Nehemiah 7:36
    2 Kings 25:3, Jeremiah 52:6
    Matthew 25:21, Matthew 25:23
    Leviticus 4:1, Leviticus 17:1, Leviticus 18:1, Leviticus 19:1, Leviticus 21:16, Leviticus 22:1, Leviticus 22:17, Leviticus 22:26, Leviticus 23:9, Leviticus 23:23, Leviticus 23:26, Leviticus 23:33, Numbers 3:5, Numbers 3:11, Numbers 3:44, Numbers 5:5, Numbers 5:11, Numbers 6:1, Numbers 8:5, Numbers 8:23, Numbers 16:23, Numbers 18:25, Numbers 25:16, Numbers 35:9
    Job 6:1, Job 9:1, Job 12:1, Job 16:1, Job 19:1, Job 21:1, Job 23:1, Job 26:1
    Psalms 60:12, Psalms 108:13
    2 Kings 25:29, Jeremiah 52:33
    2 Kings 8:20, 2 Chronicles 21:8
    2 Kings 18:19, Isaiah 36:4
    Numbers 14:26, Numbers 16:20
    1 Kings 22:11, 2 Chronicles 18:10
    Song of Solomon 2:6, Song of Solomon 8:3
    Genesis 10:14, 1 Chronicles 1:12
    1 Chronicles 3:7, 1 Chronicles 14:6
    Ezra 2:64, Nehemiah 7:66
    2 Samuel 23:23, 1 Chronicles 11:25
    2 Kings 15:3, 2 Chronicles 26:4
    2 Samuel 22:35, Psalms 18:34
    Ezra 2:4, Nehemiah 7:9
    Job 8:1, Job 18:1, Job 25:1
    1 Kings 22:16, 2 Chronicles 18:15
    Matthew 24:47, Luke 12:44
    1 Chronicles 16:34, Psalms 118:1, Psalms 118:29
    Mark 15:2, Luke 23:3
    Job 38:1, Job 40:6
    1 Kings 22:5, 2 Chronicles 18:4
    Proverbs 6:10, Proverbs 24:33
    2 Kings 19:12, Isaiah 37:12
    1 Chronicles 16:16, Psalms 105:9
    2 Kings 25:20, Jeremiah 52:26
    Ezra 2:32, Nehemiah 7:35
    2 Kings 18:24, Isaiah 36:9
    1 Kings 10:27, 2 Chronicles 9:27
    Exodus 25:33, Exodus 37:19
    Numbers 7:14, Numbers 7:20, Numbers 7:26, Numbers 7:32, Numbers 7:38, Numbers 7:44, Numbers 7:50, Numbers 7:56, Numbers 7:62, Numbers 7:68, Numbers 7:74, Numbers 7:80
    Psalms 46:7, Psalms 46:11
    Jeremiah 13:8, Jeremiah 18:5, Jeremiah 24:4, Ezekiel 17:11
    Genesis 10:28, 1 Chronicles 1:22
    1 Chronicles 16:11, Psalms 105:4
    Genesis 10:17, 1 Chronicles 1:15
    Genesis 36:33, 1 Chronicles 1:44
    Matthew 17:21, Matthew 18:11, Matthew 23:14, Mark 7:16, Mark 9:44, Mark 9:46, Mark 11:26, Mark 15:28, Luke 17:36, Luke 23:17, John 5:4, Acts 8:37, Acts 15:34, Acts 24:7, Acts 28:29, Romans 16:24
    Ezra 2:31, Nehemiah 7:34
    Matthew 26:30, Mark 14:26
    Leviticus 19:30, Leviticus 26:2
    Genesis 36:36, 1 Chronicles 1:47
    Numbers 16:44, Numbers 20:7
    Proverbs 21:9, Proverbs 25:24
    Philippians 4:23, Philemon 1:25
    2 Samuel 22:20, Psalms 18:19
    Matthew 13:42, Matthew 13:50
```

Do these duplicates also exist in the original text? (currently, I only have the Bible in English)

**Edit**: So I gonna narrow down this question (please tell me if I need to narrow more)

So there are a lot of Duplicate Bible verses, this question is only focus on the duplicate verses: PROVERBS 22:3 and PROVERBS 27:12 (but if you find more interesting duplicate verses, please add them to your answer as well).

I know that The Holy Bible has many copies through generations, so it's very hard (or impossible) to find the real original text (mmm... actually, I personally think the Bible is stored in the memory of the Jewish). So let narrow down this to just one of the copies of the old Hebrew text (again, if you find more than one that might reveal something incredible, please add them to your answer as well)

Comment: This is a great question. I've been noticing this for a very long time myself. Especially in the Psalms. +1

Comment: @123iamking  This is actually a very good question, the problem with it, as noted is that it's perhaps not specific enough, so they put it on hold. Perhaps you could retain the list of duplicates (for all of us) as just an addendum of additional information and put all the focus of your question on just the one verse. Actually, I for one, think that this is what your question does, but it still was put on hold, so it needs some editing. Please give this a try, so we can get this out of the hold status.

Comment: @robin: Thanks for notifying me :) I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look them all up, but Proverbs 22:3 and Proverbs 27:12 are not letter-for-letter identical in the Hebrew (the Masoretic text). Here's Proverbs 22:3:

> עָרוּם ׀ רָאָה רָעָה וְנִסְתָּר וּפְתָיִים עָבְרוּ וְנֶעֱנָשׁוּ׃

(I've put in the [Qere reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qere_and_Ketiv); if you don't know what that is don't worry about it.)

Here it is in the NIV:

> The prudent see danger and take refuge, but the simple keep going and suffer.

Proverbs 27:12 doesn't have the ו's, which are usually translated “but” or “and”.

> עָרוּם רָאָה רָעָה נִסְתָּר פְּתָאיִם עָבְרוּ נֶעֱנָשׁוּ׃

Here's a modified NIV to give the effect:

> The prudent see danger, take refuge; the simple keep going, suffer.

I'll just comment that there are many reasons that a verse might be duplicated.

- One author may be invoking the work of another, which is certainly common enough at the level of the phrase, if not at the level of the whole verse>
- One work might be based on facts contained in another, or could reflect the same facts independently (the Genesis/1 Chronicles example you cited
- One work might be a revision of another (which some people think is what happened with Matthew and Mark)
- As seems to have happened in this case, the book is a selection from a vast body of literature (proverbial literature), and it somehow made sense to include one proverb twice.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, by "the original text"? The Hebrew or Greek versions are not necessarily "original", isn't it. Most of the duplicate Bible verses from the list will also duplicate in other translations too. I just did a random check up against a French and a Romanian version. It is all the same: duplicate verses like in the English Bible. These duplicate Bible verses are playing an important part in the Hebrew biblical exegesis. Please see for instance the 2d rule of Hillel, G'zerah Shavah (Equivalence of expressions): An analogy is made between two separate (con)texts on the basis of a similar phrase, word or root. Likewise, the 6th rule, Kayotze Bo Mimechom Achar (Like that in another place)[cf. R’Ishmael’s 13th rule]: basically 2 passages explain one another through their similar content. Please find out more about these following the links bellow:
http://www.academia.edu/4489668/The_Middot_of_Hillel_Hillels_Hermeneutical_Rules
http://www.yashanet.com/studies/revstudy/hillel.htm
http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/hermeneutics

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. by "the original text", I mean the original text that the The Holy Bible, English Standard Version (https://www.amazon.com/Bible-English-Standard-Version-Cross-References-ebook/dp/B001EOCFU4) translated from. I'm studying your answer and hope to understand more.

Comment: @123iamking: Ok, I see. "The original text" is a problem on its own, as there is no such as thing as this. As we can find out, we do not possess nowadays the original autographs of the Bible. What we do have is many ancient copies. The Bible text used by translators is a composite made from the most reliable of the ancient manuscripts. Please find out more here: https://www.biblica.com/resources/bible-faqs/is-the-bible-we-have-today-in-english-the-same-as-the-original-bible/ ; https://ebible.com/questions/16980-what-bible-translation-is-closest-to-the-original-written-scriptures

Comment: @123iamking: <adam.baker>'s answer should be very useful for you, this why I gave it my vote. It is a list of very possible reasons for the duplicates. Yet, as "the original text" is so problematic, there is also important to see if we find out the same duplicates in different other translations in different languages (as far from the English versions as we can) and then to see how the reception was dealing with it. {to be coninued}

Comment: @123iamking @ adam.baker: If we find the duplicates in many languages, this is a sign that they were present in this "original text". If we find them discussed by commentators, this is a sign that the duplicates were not taken as textual issues, but were considered important for their meaning too. This is why I am suggesting that we could look out for a possible answer in the Hebrew exegesis. I haven't found yet this issue discussed by Christian commentators otherwise as a matter of textual criticism, which more often resulted in lists like the one that you have discovered.